# Deployment to cloud fails saying size of DiagnosticStore cannot be reduced?

Tags: c#, caching, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I recently upgraded my azure storage libraries from 1.7 to 2.1 and since then I have not been able to deploy to my cloud service. I keep getting this deployment error.

```
The size of local resources cannot be reduced. Affected local resource is DiagnosticStore in WorkerRole. Current size is 20000. Requested size is 4096.
```

I haven't enabled caching and I tried using Small and even Medium VM's but still the issue persists. Any idea where the issue might be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't deploy directly to the "Production" slot.

Deploy to the "Staging" slot (which will requisition new resoruces/sizes) and then perform a VIP Swap.

Comment: @Eoin ... I'm curious about why it would work considering staging and production environment are supposed to be identical. Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: staging and production environments are really just a logical construct at the RDFE (ie. portal/service management API) level.  And swapping between the slots is only a config change at the load balancer.  The two deployments themselves have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Guarav - Think about it like this. If you deploy once to "Production", it will put aside specific resources for that specific deployment. If you do an in-place redeploy, then those resources are already allocated, and all your doing is replacing the binaries/configs, hence you end up with a mis-match. When you deploy to staging, you are asking Azure to "Create me a completely new deployment, with new allocated resources, based on the config/binaries I'm about to upload". VIP Swapping is then just  the Virtual IPs being repointed from one deployment to the other at the load balancer.